# Extracting all my answers (and the questions)

Tags: support, images, export

I'd like to extract all the answers I have written (along with the corresponding questions). In both cases (answers and questions) I'd like to have the original text (including markup) so that I can incorporate this into other LaTeX documents, and I'd like to have any included links and images, too, if possible.

I assume that there is some clever query to do this, but I'm a query neophyte/idiot, so I need detailed step-by-step instructions, please.

I tried some of the queries mentioned [in this post](https://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/12915/backup-save-download-all-questions-and-answers-for-individual-users?s=1%7C1.0336). I managed to get the text of my answers, including the links, but I don't see a way to get my pictures.

Comment: The pictures are given as links to stackimage, right? I think you'll just have to download those on your own (or write a script that does it for you). Do you have very many images?

Comment: @mixedmath -- 54 images in 805 answers. I can download them one at a time if I have to, but I'd rather not.

Comment: Are you on a linux/mac machine, or Windows (or perhaps something else entirely)? If so, then this can be done very simply from a terminal using wget. [I'm afraid I'm not as familiar with Windows machines, but I'm sure it's not so hard to download lists of images on Windows either].

Comment: Or perhaps http://superuser.com/questions/274276/what-program-can-i-use-to-bulk-download-this-list-of-links

Comment: @mixedmath -- I'm on a Windows machine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It just so happens that I did this over the summer ([final product](https://www.apnorton.com/projects.html)).  The process wasn't great, but it worked (and I now have a 464-page hardback book of my answers with their associated questions).

General outline of my procedure:

1. Download the question data using the StackExchange Data Explorer.  My query is found [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/264023/get-questions-youve-answered-with-your-answers).
2. [Parse the returned HTML with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1110928) (don't kill me); Normal Human's [Save as LaTeX](http://normalhuman.github.io/savetex/) utility has some nice regex in the Javascript source.
3. Use `wget` and `sed` to find all links to stack.imgur.com, download the image, and replace the text with the appropriate figure environment.
4. Use the `subfiles` package to allow placing each question/answer in its own file.

If I ever get around to streamlining/debugging my Python scripts, I'll post it to GitHub and link it here.

Comment: [**Oh Yes You Can** use regexes to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4234491)... at least when you know that HTML was generated by [MarkDownSharp](https://code.google.com/p/markdownsharp/).

Comment: The "Save as LaTeX" link no longer works - using [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20190202113110/https://normalhuman.github.io/savetex/) one can see at least what it looked like.

Answer (score 5):

As a slight improvement to @apnorton's answer, I created a Python script that does it all in one step: it uses the Stack Exchange API and the `requests` Python package to download all your questions and answers across all sites and then writes them to Markdown files in sub-directories. All it takes is a single execution of a Python script. The Python script, as well as instructions on how to use it, can be found here: https://github.com/mhdadk/stack-exchange-backup